# Using variables with jQuery and embedded objects

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables

I am using a java script library that allows me to query information from a shoutcast server such as the current song playing, recent songs played, and etc which all works fine. This library places the data into a span element on the page based on it's defined ID.

Now, my issue is that I am trying to pass the contents of my span which is a string (current song title) to PHP so that I can use it for my Twitter library which uses PHP to post to Twitter.

```
<?php
// Insert your keys/tokens
$consumerKey = '';
$consumerSecret = '';
$accessToken = '';
$accessTokenSecret = '';

// Full path to twitterOAuth.php (change OAuth to your own path)
require_once('/home/soundcheck/public_html/app/twitter/auto/twitteroauth.php');
require_once('/home/soundcheck/public_html/app/twitter/auto/twitter.class');
// create new instance
$twitter = new Twitter($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $accessToken, $accessTokenSecret);
$twitter->send('testing...');       // This will send testing to twitter status!

?>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.shoutcast.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Current Song Played -->
    <script>
    // Get current song playing and load it into an element with an ID of songtitle
        $.SHOUTcast({
            host : 'live.soundcheck.xyz',
            port : 8000,
            interval : 5000,
        }).stats(function(){
            $('#songtitle').text(this.get('songtitle'));

            $(document).ready(function() {
                console.log("Document Ready!");
                var content = $('#songtitle').text();
                var nowplaying = ("#NowPlaying: " + content);


                $.ajax({
                    url: 'receiver.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { data : nowplaying },
                    success: function (result) {
                        console.log(nowplaying);

                    }
                });

            });

        });
    </script>
    <!-- Last 10 Songs Played -->
    <script>
    // Get last 10 songs playing and load it into an ul element
        $.SHOUTcast({
            host : 'live.soundcheck.xyz',
            port : 8000
        }).played(function(tracks){
            $('ul').html('');
            $.each(tracks,function(k,track){
                $('ul').append('<li>'+track.title+'</li>');
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
This SPAN has the current song title within it upon page load which is good. I want to pass this     data to my PHP above to post to twitter.
    <span id="songtitle" name="songtitle"></span>
    <ul></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Any assistance with this will be very helpful.. I have looked at so many places with no luck and this is getting very frustrating.

Regards,

Comment: Try wrapping `$(document.ready(function{...})` around the whole thing, not just the code in the callback.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was able to get this working using jQuery.POST - If you'd like I can post the working code.

Comment: If you solved the problem, and you think the answer will be useful to future readers, you should post an answer.

Comment: answer has been posted.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted my updated code which successfully sends a jQuery variable to PHP using AJAX upon a page load.

Here is the HTML/JAVASCRIPT

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.shoutcast.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Current Song Played -->
    <script>
        // Get current song playing and load it into an element with an ID of songtitle
        $.SHOUTcast({
            host : 'live.soundcheck.xyz',
            port : 8000,
            interval : 5000,
        }).stats(function(){
            $('#songtitle').text(this.get('songtitle'));

            $(document).ready(function() {
                console.log("Document Ready!");
                var content = $('#songtitle').text();
                var nowplaying = ("#NowPlaying: " + content);
                console.log('TOP' + nowplaying);

                $.post("receiver.php", //Required URL of the page on server
                    {   // Data Sending With Request To Server
                        name:nowplaying,
                    },
                    function(response){  // Required Callback Function
                        alert("Response: " + response);  //  "response"  receives - whatever written in echo of above PHP script.
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
    <!-- Last 10 Songs Played -->
    <script>
        // Get last 10 songs playing and load it into an ul element
        $.SHOUTcast({
            host : 'live.soundcheck.xyz',
            port : 8000
        }).played(function(tracks){
            $('ul').html('');
            $.each(tracks,function(k,track){
                $('ul').append('<li>'+track.title+'</li>');
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <span id="songtitle" name="songtitle"></span>
    <ul></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the PHP code

```
<?php

// Insert your keys/tokens
$consumerKey = '';
$consumerSecret = '';
$accessToken = '';
$accessTokenSecret = '';

// Full path to twitterOAuth.php (change OAuth to your own path)
require_once('/home/soundcheck/public_html/app/twitter/auto/twitteroauth.php');
require_once('/home/soundcheck/public_html/app/twitter/auto/twitter.class');
// create new instance
$twitter = new Twitter($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $accessToken, $accessTokenSecret);

if($_POST["name"])
{
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    // Here, you can also perform some database query operations with above values.
    // echo "Welcome ". $name ."!"; // Success Message
    echo $name; // Success Message
    $tag = ('@ http://soundcheck.xyz  #radio - powered by: http://buzzzhost.com');
    $twitter->send($name .= $tag);       // This will send testing to twitter status!
}


?>
```

I hope this will help someone out there as I was searching for a long time for a good option.

Comment: `$.post` is just a shorthand for `$.ajax`. If one works, so should the other. It looks like the only real change is from `{ data : nowplaying }` to `{ name : nowplaying }`.